# Python regex replace with return match

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string

```
p='12.04.2020 - 17:00 - 13.04.2020 10:00'
```

How do I replace the first dash (-), which is a mistake, with an empty space?

I tried with

```
re.sub("(20\d*) - (\d*):","\1 \2:",p)

'12.04.\x01 \x02:00 - 13.04.2020 10:00'
```

but it doesn't return the matches.

**Edit:** there may be multiple such patterns and there may not be a dash in that position, so it has to be specific, I cannot just replace the first found dash.

Comment: you didn't match on \. (only digits \d), and it only matches  one dash.  If you only need to replace the first dash seen, why aren't you just doing `p.replace('-','',1)`?  Do you need to verify the format of the string?

Comment: `index = p.index("-");p=p[:index] + "" + p[index+1:]` - Bad way of doing

Comment: `p.replace('-', '', 1) `?

Comment: @cs95 No because there are possibly multiple patterns. And also because there may not be a dash at that place, so that code would replace the second dash, which is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `r` modifier to prevent escaping \d to d and \1 to 1

```
re.sub(r"(20\d*) - (\d*):",r"\1 \2:",p)
```

Comment: You can also use `\\d` and `\\1`.  `r` (aka raw) modifier prefix is more convenient.  Don't you need to also account for 17:20 - 13?